# No USB entry in Bios of repurposed laptop, can't boot; how to write a bootable CD

Tags: usb

New User. Re-purposing a circa. 2005 HP dv1220 laptop to LINUX. Have Downloaded Ubuntu to a Flash drive. Into Bios to  change Boot Order -- NO USB entry in Bios!!
Does this mean there's NO way to boot from flash drive?

Laptop has a CD reader (Not DVD), don't remember if it writes or how to do it if it does. Someone please point me to instructions to write/burn a cd disk and I'll put Ubuntu on it.

Also, if there's a better place to ask my 'newbie' questions, please let me know.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The PLOP boot manager was created for just this purpose: https://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/download.html

Comment: You'll need to burn Plop to a CD, and the use that to boot from the USB you have (Ubuntu is too big to fit on a CD). If your laptop can burn CD's (Check for a "Compact disc rewritable" logo  on the CD drive), you can burn it from windows. If not, maybe you can find another computer. I'd also recommend one of the more lightweight versions of Ubuntu (such as Lubuntu or Ubuntu MATE), as they'll run better on your laptop.